Movie from 70s or 80s on screen in Furious 7
In Fast & Furious 7 opening, Han was killed by Deckard Shaw. After that Toretto went to visit Hobbs in the hospital after being beat up by Deckard. Hobbs was watching a movie or a TV Show which looked like it is a 70s or 80s movie (may be 90s I can't be so sure).
Can anyone tell what is the name of that movie or TV show?

It was a TV show not any movie. At that time Toretto said to hobbs that "You risk life and limb to save the free world and what do they give you? Jell-O and a bad 70's TV show"That was some wrestling show.

What is the name of it?

I am sure that he watched "The Incredible Hulk", TV show from 1978. When Dom entered the room, the background can be heard: 

I'll show you around as far as the roads go.
  It's your own private world.
  That's why the animals I import here can survive.  

It is a conversation between David Banner and Michael Sutton from episode "The Snare" (season 3, episode 9), and if you go to the next link The Hulk: The Snare Part 1, you can find that around 4:41.
Like Dominic said "...bad seventies TV show."

We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

What make you so sure it was "The Incredible Hulk"
